# recursive sequentially powerset function in python

Tags: python, recursion

what I expect for [1,2,3] ->

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3]
[2]
[2, 3]
[3]
```

but my function give this result, I can not fix it ->

```
def foo(L,first,last,Output):
    if first>=last:
        return
    for i in range(first ,last):
        print(Output+[L[i]])
        foo(L,first+1,last,Output+[L[i]])
        


foo([1,2,3],0,3,[])


[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3]
[1, 3, 3]
[2]
[2, 2]
[2, 2, 3]
[2, 3]
[2, 3, 3]
[3]
[3, 2]
[3, 2, 3]
[3, 3]
[3, 3, 3]
```

and in some situation I want to stop calculation and continue with others:

let say if 1 and 2 get come together , dont continue anymore

-> for [1,2,3] and (1,2)

what I expect :

```
[1]
[1, 3]
[2]
[2, 3]
[3]
```

iterative function is also good for me

Comment: Let's consider `foo([1, 2, 3], 0, 3, [])`. The first element of `[1, 2, 3]` is `1`. Every subset can either contain 1, or not contain 1. So, you want to collect the results of `foo([1, 2, 3], 1, 3, [])`, which are the subsets that don't contain 1, and the results of `foo([1, 2, 3], 1, 3, [1])`, which are the subsets that contain 1. So you should have two recursive calls.

Comment: PS I strongly suggest using the `return` keyword, and avoiding `print`. Although, you can keep some `print` in for debugging purposes, but remove them when you're finished. The actual return value (the list of subsets) should be returned with `return`.

Answer (score 1):

**inductive reasoning**

Another way to think about the problem doesn't involve ranges, indexes or incrementing them, leading to many [off-by-one errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). Instead we can reason about the problem [inductively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) -

1. If the input `t` is empty, yield the empty set
2. (inductive) `t` has at least one element. For all `p` in the recursive sub-problem `powerset(t[1:])`, yield `p` and yield `p` with the first element, `t[0]` prepended.

```py
def powerset(t):
  if not t:
    yield ()                       # 1. empty t
  else:
    for p in powerset(t[1:]):      # 2. at least one element
      yield p
      yield (t[0], *p)
```

By using `yield` we move the desired effect *outside* of the `powerset` function. This allows the caller to decide what happens with each produced set -

```py
for p in powerset("abc"):
  print(p)                   # <- desired effect
```

```py
()
('a',)
('b',)
('a', 'b')
('c',)
('a', 'c')
('b', 'c')
('a', 'b', 'c')
```

```py
for p in powerset("abc"):
  print("".join(p))     # <- different effect
```

```
a
b
ab
c
ac
bc
abc
```

**changing the order**

*I just want to process sequentially as I showed in the example*.

The particular order you asked for can be achieved by reordering the yields. I also made an adjustment to remove the empty set from the output -

1. if the input `t` is empty, stop
2. (inductive) `t` has at least one element

   - yield the singleton set of the first element, `t[0]`
   - prepend the first element to each result of the sub-problem `powerset(t[1:])` and yield
   - yield each result of the sub-problem `powerset(t[1:])`

```py
def powerset(t):
  if not t:
    return                 # 1.
  else:
    yield (t[0],)          # 2.
    yield from map(lambda p: (t[0], *p), powerset(t[1:]))
    yield from powerset(t[1:])
```

Notice above we compute `powerset(t[1:])` twice. This is wasteful and can be avoided using `itertools.tee` -

```py
from itertools import tee

def powerset(t):
  if not t: return
  yield (t[0],)
  left, right = tee(powerset(t[1:]))          # <- tee left & right
  yield from map(lambda p: (t[0], *p), left)  # <- left
  yield from right                            # <- right
```

```py
for p in powerset("abc"):
  print(p)
```

```py
('a',)
('a', 'b')
('a', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'c')
('b',)
('b', 'c')
('c',)
```

**list of all subsets**

*Is it possible to do it without using yield? I need to keep it in a global list*

Python uses iterables throughout its standard library. The prescribed way is to use `yield` however it's easy to convert to list using `list` -

```py
result = list(powerset("abc"))
print(result)
```

```py
[('a',), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c'), ('b',), ('b', 'c'), ('c',)]
```

**without using `yield`**

If you have some compelling reason where `powerset` *must* return an array instead of an iterable, the transformation is elementary. Notice the structure of the program is identical -

```py
def powerset(t):
  if not t: return []
  result = list(powerset(t[1:]))
  return [
    (t[0],),
    *map(lambda p: (t[0], *p), result),
    *result
  ]
```

```py
print(powerset("abc"))
```

```py
[('a',), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c'), ('b',), ('b', 'c'), ('c',)]
```

Comment: `()
('a',)
('a', 'b')
('a', 'b', 'c')` it must be sequential

Comment: @XLVII what is the question?

Comment: It's a bit complicated, it's about combinatorics. I just want to process sequentially as I showed in the example.

Comment: @XLVII I didn't realize the specific order was critical. I made an update to the post. Let me know if you have any questions ^_^

Comment: Is it possible to do it without using yield? I don't fully understand the algorithm, I need to keep it in a global list

Comment: @XLVII the way to convert any iterable to a list in python is to use `list`, ie `list(powerset("abc"))`. I added an update to my answer to show another approach without using generators.